# Wilson's Theorem converse

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am currently working through *Contemporary Abstract Algebra* 10th edition by Gallian. I have come across a problem that looks like Wilson's Theorem from number theory.

The problem: If $n$ is a positive integer greater than $1$ and $(n-1)! \equiv 1 \mod n$ then $n$ is prime.

I don't have a problem with the proof but I am trying to connect this to the converse of Wilson's Theorem, since the theorem states that for any prime $p$, we have $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \mod p$. It is mainly the sign that is confusing me.

Comment: This is Exercise 0.20 of the book I mentioned above. I wrote it exactly the way it is in the book

Comment: Probably the intended statement was with -1 instead, but the statement is true either way (and the proof is basically the same).

Comment: Yea, I just worked through the proof and yea it works exactly the same. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If $n$ is a composite number, that is, there exists $1<p<n$ such that $p$ divides $n$ and $p$ is prime. Hence $p\mid n$ and $p \mid (n-1)!$, so $(n-1)!$ and $n$ are not coprime. This proves the converse of Wilson's theorem, but we can do better.

If $n\not=p^2$, then $p$ and $n/p$ are two distinct numbers amongst $1, 2, \cdots, n-1$, so $n\mid (n-1)!$, $(n-1)!\equiv 0 \mod n$.

If $n=p^2$ and $p>2$, then $1<p<2p<p^2$ are two distinct numbers amongst $1, 2, \cdots, n-1=p^2-1$, hence $(n-1)!\equiv 0\mod n$.

We're left with the case $p=2, n=p^2=4$, in which case $3!\equiv 2\mod 4$.

In all,

$$(n-1)!\equiv\begin{cases} -1 \mod n & \text{ if } n \text{ is prime }  \\ 2 & \text{ if } n=4 \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that this statement were true. Follow that line of reasoning.

Start with an integer $n > 1$ such that $(n-1)! \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. By this conjecture, $n$ is prime. But then Wilson gives us that $(n-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$, so we have $1 \equiv -1 \pmod{n}$ or equivalently $2 \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$, which means that $n = 2$.

Clearly, this is too restrictive!

So, yeah, your suspicion is merited. The claim as written is false and likely a typo. In fact, Wilson's Theorem is an *if and only if* statement.

Comment: The claim holds... because the congruence holds for $n\gt1$ if and only if $n=2$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)

Comment: I think it is a typo